# Show that a map of sets is continuous if its composition with other functions is

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Problem: Let $Y, E, B$ be topological spaces with $Y$ locally path connected.  Suppose $p: E \rightarrow B$ is a covering map, with $g: Y \rightarrow E$ a map of sets.  If $p \circ g$ is continuous, as well as $g \circ \gamma$ for every path $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow Y$, then $g$ is continuous.

I haven't gotten very far here.  If $O$ is open in $E$, I know that $p$ is an open map, so $pO$, hence $(p \circ g)^{-1}pO= g^{-1}p^{-1}pO$, is open in $Y$.  But this set only contains $g^{-1}O$.

I was thinking I would somehow need to use the lifting correspondence for covering maps.

Comment: You can assume $Y$ path connected and locally path connected without loss of generality. For every $x\in Y$ there's a path connected neighborhood $U$ and $g$ is continuous in $x$ iff $g|_U$ is.